# Console\ConsoleMakeCommand not found when updating Laravel composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I've noticed some errors this morning trying to update composer in `Laravel 4.2`

```
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConsoleMakeCommand' n  
  ot found in /usr/local/var/www/avionerd/vendor/indatus/dispatcher/src/Indatus/Dispatcher/C  
  ommands/Make.php on line 21
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try and delete the `/vendor` directory and do `composer update` again.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was actually solved both removing /vendor and upgrading to latest indatus/dispatcher version **"indatus/dispatcher": "1.*"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

Make sure that you reference the latest release of dispatcher in your composer.json file (instead of dev-master):

```
"indatus/dispatcher": "1.*"
```

Then remove your vendor/ directory and do a composer update again. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I ran composer using PHP5.3, ran into issues, and then ran it again using PHP5.5 without first clearing the previous vendor files. Deleting the vendor folder solved the problem.

*UPDATE*

Also, i was running composer in two different ways. In the first case I ran "composer" and in the other case I ran "php composer.phar". I stuck with "php composer.phar" and everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The problem was actually solved both removing /vendor and upgrading to latest indatus/dispatcher version "indatus/dispatcher": "1.*"

Thanks!